# Simulation loading never ends on Vivado

Tags: testing, vhdl, simulation, xilinx, vivado

I'm trying to test my VHDL code, for example:

```
entity fulladder4bit is
    port( a,b,cin: in std_logic;
          s,cout: out std_logic);
end fulladder4bit;

architecture FA4 of fulladder4bit is
    signal p,g: std_logic;
begin
    p<= a xor b;
    g<= a and b;
    s<= p xor cin;
    cout<= g or (p and cin);
end FA4;
```

So I wrote this testbench:

```
entity fulladd4_testbench is
end fulladd4_testbench;

architecture FA4_TB of fulladd4_testbench is
    component fulladder4bit is
        port( a,b,cin: in bit;
              s,cout: out bit);
    end component;

    signal iA: bit;
    signal iB: bit;
    signal iCin: bit;
    signal oS: bit;
    signal oCout: bit;

begin
    fa4: fulladder4bit port map(iA, iB, iCin, oS, oCout);

process
    begin
        iA<='1';
        iB<='1';
        iCin<='0';    
end process;
end FA4_TB;

end FA4_TB;
```

I followed a tutorial (released by my teacher) and I clicked on Run Synthesis and after Run Simulation but Simulation loading never ends, now I push on Cancel and neither for this the loading never ends!
Do I make some mistakes?

I'm using Vivado

Comment: The process in the test bench will loop indefinitely. You need to end it with a `wait;` statement.

Comment: Aren't there any delta saturation engine in Vivado ? I'm pretty sure that modelsim would have complained about it. I'm surprised.

Comment: @JHBonarius I added `wait;` statement before `end process;` statemend but it's the same! thank you btw
@grorel no, I removed and re-installed Vivado today but it's the same! thank you for reply me

Comment: The testbench instantiation of fulladder4bit is likely unbound. Note the component declaration uses type bit while the entity fulladder4bit declarations uses std_logic (which requires package std_logic_1164 referenced in a use clause with a library clause referencing ieee in the context clause of the root declarative region).

Comment: @user1155120 I tried to convert all `std_logic` statements into `bit` statements and it gives me 2 errors

Comment: and what does `C:/Users/darkpassenger/Documents/Universit/Elettronica_Digitale/workspace_vivado/project_1/project_1.sim/sim_1/behav/xsim/xvhdl.log` tell you? ;)

Comment: What's the log say is wrong? Your testbench has two architecture `end FA4_TB;` statements. And don't forget the wait statement in the unnamed process in the the testbench. (e.g. `wait for 20 ns; wait;`, so simulation time passes). There's no detection method for processes not suspending.

Comment: thanks for reply, the problem was the two `end FA4_TB;` statements (my stupidity, sorry) and now it doesn't give me errors; but the loop still runs! I don't understand why if I cancel the simulation it goes in loop while canceling it! I tried to install a previous version(from 2018.1 to 2017.4) and it's the same
@JHBonarius @user1155120